# RS-232 serial communication using C++ and How to transform LabView VI to c++ code

Tags: c++

I try to develop a program to control the Lakeshore 331 temperature controller. Basically, I use the structure of Createfile(),Writefile(),and Readfile from some literatures. After a month, I think I can open a port, write some word, but never read anything. I suspected about problem of Baudrate, parity, stopbits(which I cannot really control by DCB) and also the time. In the other hand, in LV, using just a small program, then works correctly. Here, I would like to ask if anyone can either transform this LV basic code to C++ for me or correct my old C++ program, I will really appreciate.

This is my C++ code,; Note that if I write the word *IDN?  , the program should say"LS331 ...." but nothing happened.

```
int main(){

HANDLE hSerial;
HANDLE screen = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

char datarecv[3];
char szBuff[2]={0}; //= {0};
DWORD dwBytesRead;
DCB dcbSerialParams = {0};
dcbSerialParams.DCBlength=sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
BOOL fSuccess;



DWORD dwWritten, dwReading;


hSerial = CreateFile("COM4",GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,0,0,OPEN_EXISTING,0,0);

 COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts;                   

  timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 1;
  timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 1;
  timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 1;
  timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 1;
  timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 1;
  if (!SetCommTimeouts(hSerial, &timeouts))
  PrintError("E014_SetCommtimeout failed");
GetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams);
dcbSerialParams.BaudRate=CBR_9600;
dcbSerialParams.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE;
dcbSerialParams.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_ENABLE;
dcbSerialParams.fOutxCtsFlow = 1;
dcbSerialParams.fRtsControl = DTR_CONTROL_HANDSHAKE;

dcbSerialParams.Parity = 1;
dcbSerialParams.StopBits = TWOSTOPBITS;
dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;

SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams);


static const char *buf={"*IDN?"};
char buff[7];
char bufff[10];
 DWORD read = 0;
 int writee=6;
 DWORD write=64; // Number of bytes to write to serial port
 //buf[0] = 2; // Decmial value to write to serial port

WriteFile(hSerial,buf,writee,&write,NULL); 
printf("write=%i\n",write);
ReadFile(hSerial,&bufff,100,&dwReading,NULL);
printf("write=%i\n",bufff);


//DWORD i;
//for (i=0; i<read; i++)
//printf("%i ", (unsigned char)buff[6]);




  CloseHandle(hSerial);
```

And This is the LV example; I just write the *IDN? >>> program shows  LS331.....

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dm9mbffaj9zew8k/Untitled.png?dl=0

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You diligently set up the DCB, and then immediately overwrite it with the call to `GetCommState`. Change an order to:

```
getCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams);
dcbSerialParams.BaudRate=CBR_9600;
...
dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;
SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams);
```

That should solve a communication setup problem.

Comment: When I move the getCommstate above all DCB there seem to have an error when compiled, why?

Answer (score 0):

Your call to GetCommState is overwriting all the settings you made in the dcbSerialParams. You must call GetCommState *before* you set the params.

The WriteFile and ReadFile calls should use the COM port handle, not the Std handle.

Comment: I move the GetCommstate up above DCB and then replace my HANDLE screen to hSerial but they do not give any response. It seem to have an error about getcomstate, and the reading byte = 0. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: How can we help you if you do not show the changed code and do not show the exact error message?